# ASP.NET Core: Using different authentication method based on the current request

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core, multi-tenant

I am working on an API application which should support multiple customers. I plan to have an Azure AD B2C tenant for each customer. Based on a value in the header of the request I want to "select" the right B2C tenant.

I can't figure out how to set this up. I had hoped I could use `MapWhen` on the `IApplicationBuilder` with one section for each customer, but authentication is set up in the `ConfigureServices` method in Startup.cs  and not in the `Configure` method.
I can make my application work if I call `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication` in `ConfigureServices`, but then I always target the same B2C instance.

So how do I do this?
Or am I trying to solve to problem the wrong way?

Comment: Maybe these URLs may be to any help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/overview https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/woodgrove-groceries-demo

Comment: Thanks @RoarS. but no they don't address the problem. I have no trouble using B2C with only one tenant, but using it with multiple in an ASP.NET 3.1 appication. B2C is just the authentication system I have selected. The main problem is within ASP.NET.